# How to create HTML5 Android Application?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I am newbie, and i don't know how to create HTML5 based android application.

1.) Could anyone give me some workaround on how to create HTML5 based application for android platform.

2.) What tools/libraries should i use in creating application ?

if possible, then please share the links.

Comment: i have edited the question to have valid answers

Comment: Stack Overflow is [a Q&A resource, not a help forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92115/228805). It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers, not a place to ask open-ended questions seeking broad overviews, tutorials, introductory info, or general pointers about getting started. Please read the [About] page and the following advice on asking questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK enables you to create a web browser app. Just like Google chrome. You can then deploy the App to Google play store so people can download it and Install it on Android  phones and tablets.

Jquery mobile is a popular framework that makes it easy to create a mobile web App that can be viewed in a browser.

Put the two together and you have a mobile APP that can be started on the phone just like any other app and it looks and feels just like a native APP.

Once you create your Android SDK webview App you can move the JQM folder in the resources folder and tell webview to load the index page of your web app when the app starts. When you create your first app and get the hang of it you will see its very easy.

Here is a Tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRa4yMjoI7c

But JQM still lacks a few things from what native written apps can do but its getting there. The latest version 1.4 is quite good but future versions will be even better and have more abilities.

The good thing about JQM Apps is that they can be viewed on any browser so it can reach more people and more platforms.

If you want to access some of the mobile phones inbuilt devices such as the camera or SD card with JQM then you need an addition to the Android SDk called Phonegap.